# How do i know using httpwebrequest and webresponse when a file download is completed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void downloadFile(Int32 fileNr)
        {
            FileStream writer = null;
            m_currentFileSize = 0;
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadAttempting);

            FileInfo file = this.Files[fileNr];
            FileInfo fileFirstDateTime = this.Files[0];
            FileInfo fileLastDateTime = this.Files[19];
            Int64 size = 0;

            Byte[] readBytes = new Byte[this.PackageSize];
            Int32 currentPackageSize;
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch speedTimer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            Int32 readings = 0;
            Exception exc = null;
            writer = LocalDirectorySettings(file);
            HttpWebRequest webReq;
            HttpWebResponse webResp = null;

            try
            {
                webReq = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(this.Files[fileNr].Path);
                webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

                size = webResp.ContentLength;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { exc = ex; }

            m_currentFileSize = size;
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadStarted);

            if (exc != null)
            {
                bgwDownloader.ReportProgress((Int32)InvokeType.FileDownloadFailedRaiser, exc);
            }
            else
            {
                m_currentFileProgress = 0;
                while (m_currentFileProgress < size && !bgwDownloader.CancellationPending)
                {
                    while (this.IsPaused) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); }

                    speedTimer.Start();

                    currentPackageSize = webResp.GetResponseStream().Read(readBytes, 0, this.PackageSize);

                    m_currentFileProgress += currentPackageSize;
                    m_totalProgress += currentPackageSize;
                    fireEventFromBgw(Event.ProgressChanged);
                    try
                    {
                        writer.Write(readBytes, 0, currentPackageSize);
                    }
                    catch(Exception eee)
                    {
                        string myeee = eee.ToString();
                    }
                    readings += 1;

                    if (readings >= this.StopWatchCyclesAmount)
                    {
                        m_currentSpeed = (Int32)(this.PackageSize * StopWatchCyclesAmount * 1000 / (speedTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + 1));
                        speedTimer.Reset();
                        readings = 0;
                    }
                }

                speedTimer.Stop();
                writer.Close();
                webResp.Close();
                if (!bgwDownloader.CancellationPending) { fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadSucceeded); }
            }
            fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadStopped);
        }
```

The bgwDownloader

```
private BackgroundWorker bgwDownloader = new BackgroundWorker();
```

The dowork event

```
private void bgwDownloader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 fileNr = 0;
            countFilesNames = 0;

            if (this.SupportsProgress) { calculateFilesSize(); }

            if (!Directory.Exists(this.LocalDirectory)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(this.LocalDirectory); }

            while (fileNr < this.Files.Count && !bgwDownloader.CancellationPending)
            {
                m_fileNr = fileNr;
                downloadFile(fileNr);

                if (bgwDownloader.CancellationPending)
                {
                    fireEventFromBgw(Event.DeletingFilesAfterCancel);
                    cleanUpFiles(this.DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel ? 0 : m_fileNr, this.DeleteCompletedFilesAfterCancel ? m_fileNr + 1 : 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    fileNr += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

In the backgroundworker completed event it's getting to the completed event only when all the files download completed.

But i need to to create event for each file download completed.
The question if i need ot do it somehow with the backgroundworker or the httpwebrequest webresponde ? And how ?

If it's needed i will upload the whole class it's a bit long.

Update

This is in form1 how i subscribe to the FileDownloadSucceeded event:

```
downloader.FileDownloadSucceeded += new EventHandler(downloader_Succeeded);
```

Then in the event

```
private void downloader_Succeeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countFilesDownloaded++;
            label6.Text = countFilesDownloaded.ToString();
            RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
        }
```

The problem is when i put a breakpoint inside the event on the last line the RichTextBoxExtensions like it's getting there once. The downloaded file is 0 bytes size. Then i make continue it stop in this event once again second time this time the file is in the right size fully downloaded or written.

So i need somehow to check in this event when it finished the download complete.
How can i do it ?

I want to make some manipulation on the downloaded file/s in this event but i need to make sure the file was downloaded finished and i checked now with a breakpoint and only on the second time it's getting to the event the file is completed downloaded/written to the hard disk.

Update

My main goal here is that i added this method to form1

```
public static Image[] GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(Image IMG)
        {
            List<Image> IMGs = new List<Image>();
            int Length = IMG.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

            for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
            {
                IMG.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
                IMGs.Add(new Bitmap(IMG));
                IMG.Dispose();
            }

            return IMGs.ToArray();
        }
```

And i want that each file that was downloaded to extract/parse the frames gifs images from the file all the files are animated gifs so in the FileDownloadSucceeded event i added before the line:

```
Image img = new Bitmap(downloader.fileName);
```

The event

```
private void downloader_Succeeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countFilesDownloaded++;
            label6.Text = countFilesDownloaded.ToString();
            RichTextBoxExtensions.UpdateText(richTextBox1, "Ready: ", "Downloaded: ", Color.Green);
            Image img = new Bitmap(downloader.fileName);
        }
```

In fileName i see: C:\New folder (3)\Countries\Europe\07032017_223558\Europe---07032017_223558384.gif

The file is exist on the hard disk. But i'm getting exception on this line:

```
Image img = new Bitmap(downloader.fileName);

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at DownloaderPro.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Chocolade\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Parameter is not valid.
       Source=System.Drawing
       StackTrace:
            at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
            at DownloaderPro.Form1.downloader_Succeeded(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Chocolade\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\Form1.cs:line 347
            at DownloaderPro.FileDownloader.bgwDownloader_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Chocolade\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\DownloaderPro\FileDownloader.cs:line 549
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ProgressReporter(Object arg)
       InnerException:
```

This is the complete class with the backgroundworker:

[Class FileDownloader](http://pastebin.com/WKKKN86u)

And this is the project i used winrar:

[Project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=84098353035220551553)

Comment: You may want to look at the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress and OnReportProgress event. It takes a ProgressChangedEventArgs that has an object property called UserState that you can pass back information (like a string that says "File 'X' has finished downloading". So when WebRequest finishes, raise ReportProgress .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see there is allready an event firing when a filedownload is completed.

```
fireEventFromBgw(Event.FileDownloadSucceeded)
```

Just subscribe to it when creating your backgroundworker.

EDIT:

You only uploded the sln file. Not much to see there.
After looking to the code of FileDownloader.cs it looks like you didn´t wrote this "monster" on your own.

I´d like to suggest a different approuch:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadFile(source, target);
```

where source is the url and target the Path where to download to. For simple pictures it should do the trick. Thist approuch is sync.

After that:

```
var frames = GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(new Bitmap(target));
```

For multiple Files put all in a loop.

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention that i subscribe to this event already in Form1. I updated my question now with this part if you can see my updated part in the question please. I used a breakpoint now and i found what is the problem but not sure how to handle it. It seems like when it's getting to the event only after two times the file is written or finished downloaded on the first time when it's getting to the FileDownloadSucceeded the file is 9 bytes or sometimes 12kb or other size but only on the second time the file is in the right size.

Comment: Now i tried again and now it was getting to the event only once each time a file downloaded. And files seems to be fine on the hard disk. Not sure what is going on. I will update my question once again with what is my main goal.

Comment: Ok updated last time my question. Sorry for that. Now with what i'm trying to do in the event and what exception i'm getting. The whole problem from the start was the exception. And also that sometimes it's getting to the event and the file downloaded fine finished but sometimes i see the file is in 0 bytes size and only on the second time it's getting to the event the file is fine. Not sure why. But if i'm not using breakpoints in this event at all and let the program keep working in the end all the files are fine. So i wonder what is going on with this event ? And how to solve it.

Comment: @DanielHalfoni Put a breakpoint where the event is raised and check the state of the file. The event shouldn´t be raised several times. Please provide the complete class where you create your Backgroundworker or upload your project so we can see what it does.

Comment: I added to my question at the bottom two links one for the class FileDownloader.cs at pastebin.com and the second link is my project the full project. http://pastebin.com/WKKKN86u and http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=84098353035220551553